# When is require() being executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Lets assume I have *2 JS* Files and I am exporting *2 Arrays*. I have the goal to process these arrays somehow.

*In the following I will use testcode to illustrate the result. Doesn´t matter if it works or not*.

---

**sender.js**

```
let arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let arr2 = ['D', 'E', 'F'];

module.exports.arr1  = arr1;
module.exports.arr2  = arr2;
```

---

**receiver.js**

```
const sended = require('./sender.js');

function testfunc(arr1, arr2){
    // DO STH WITH THAT ARRAYS
};

let test = testfunc(sended.arr1, sended.arr2);
```

---

**my question**

is the *require* executed in the beginning and does the rest of the JS code wait until the variables *arr1* and *arr2* are loaded?

How can I be sure that *testfunc(send.arr1, send.arr2)* is executed with *send.arr1* and *send.arr2* not beeing *undefined* since the function was called before the require statement?

Hope it is clear what I want to know.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. You're *not* calling the function before `require()`, it's the first line of the file. Are you having an actual problem in a real project?

Comment: So you are sayin that this part is synchronous? If I would have placed the require **after** *let test ...* I would have had the problem I described above?

Comment: If you have `testfunc(sended.arr1); const sended = whatever;` it'll obviously *never* work regardless of what "whatever" is, because you're trying to use a variable that doesn't exist yet. But yes, `require()` does return the exports immediately (otherwise it would be completely useless in practice.)

Comment: What environment is this? Is this a CommonJS (node.js) or ESM environment? I think that *might* have an impact. Node does requires synchronously but in ESM, require is meant to be the async mechanism to bring in dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js [`require` function](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) (from the [CommonJS modules standard](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules)) is synchronous. Your code just works.